# Show Each function is equivalent using 2 conditions.(Real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

It is might be easy for you.

- The Question

There are functions $ f, g, c, s $

$f,g : R \rightarrow R  $ and  $s,c : R \rightarrow R  $   ($R$ is a set of the real number)

These functions satisfy the below conditions

(1) $f'(x)=g(x) $ , $g'(x)=-f(x) $ and  $s'(x)=c(x), c'(x)=-s(x) $

(2) $f(0)=s(0) =0 $ and $g(0)=c(0) =1$

Show  $ f(x)=s(x), g(x)=c(x) $ for all x $\in R$

When I saw this quetstion, put $h(x) = f(x)-s(x) $  and tried to show $h'(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $R$
(This means you know, $h=0$ which means $f-s=0$)

But Couldn't find any method or hint.
Please let me know the simplest method.

Comment: Put $h(x)=(f(x)-s(x))^2+(g(x)-c(x))^2$.

Comment: $r,s$ or $s,c$?

Comment: @Kelenner Your comment appeared while I was typing. If you change it to an "answer" I'll delete mine. (Until recently I would have posted this as a comment instead of an answer, feeling it was silly to make a big deal of such a small thing. But I read something that convinced me posting it as an "answer" is better - makes finding information on the site easier...)

Comment: @David C Ullrich Thank you very much for your proposition, but I think that there no need to change something. In fact as I have written only a few words and you a complete solution, I have surely found this trick after you...Thanks again, but change nothing(+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is immediate from basic uniqueness results for differential equations ($f''+f=0$, $c''+c=0$, $f(0)=c(0)$ and $f'(0)=c'(0)$, so $f=c$.) A cute direct proof: Define $$\phi(x)=(f(x)-c(x))^2+(g(x)-s(x))^2.$$Show that $\phi'(x)=0$ and deduce that $\phi(x)=\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: REALLY Cute proof ! Is there another method without Using differential equations, Mr. David?

Comment: @se-hyuckyang We have a DE proof and a non-DE proof; you want _another_ nnon-DE proof? (Btw please wait until we see whether Kelenner posts his comment as an answer before upvoting or accepting mine - he got there first.)

Comment: C.Ullrich.  Yes. I want the non-DE proof because I want to know another viewpoint, Thank you :)